# generic relation model declaration

Tags: django, django-models, generic-relations

Just a quick noob question. Do I need to have content_type, object_id, and content_object every time I use GenericRelation in models? I get the concept behind generic relation but I'm confused on how to implement it.

Below is the setup.

**Address** - a generic content type; to be used in different models.

**Company** - a simple model that uses address generic content type.

**Person**  - a simple model that uses address generic content type.

Is it essential to have these 3 attributes in all models? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this fields only inside `Address` model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

In models `Company` and `Person` you just specify reverse generic relation with `GenericRelation`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
class Company(models.Model):
    addresses = GenericRelation(Address)

class Person(models.Model):
    addresses = GenericRelation(Address)
```

with this you can get address assosiated with person like this:

```
 person.addresses.all()
```